# Problem with Maven Multi Module Project trying to get local module from artifactory

Tags: java, maven, module, artifactory, dependency-management

I haven't worked with multi-module Maven projects in a while but I am trying to establish the following projects structure:

[image]

So, you can see I have a group of projects being "helper-automation-tool" the parent one. The base pom.xml definition for that parent is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.proofofconcept.hat</groupId>
<artifactId>helper-automation-tool</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>helper-automation-tool</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.proofofconcept.hat </groupId>
            <artifactId>helper-automation-tool-dataobjects</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.proofofconcept.hat </groupId>
            <artifactId>helper-automation-tool-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.proofofconcept.hat</groupId>
            <artifactId>helper-automation-tool-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.proofofconcept.hat</groupId>
            <artifactId>helper-automation-tool-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.proofofconcept.hat</groupId>
            <artifactId>helper-automation-tool-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<modules>
    <module>helper-automation-tool-dataobjects</module>
    <module>helper-automation-tool-utils</module>
    <module>helper-automation-tool-core</module>
    <module>helper-automation-tool-api</module>
    <module>helper-automation-tool-ui</module>
</modules>
```

Some modules should have dependencies between them, I started trying to make the "helper-automation-tool-core" has the "helper-automation-tool-dataobjects" as one of the dependencies, here's the configuration for both of them:

helper-automation-tools-dataobjects

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>helper-automation-tool</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.proofofconcept.hat</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>helper-automation-tool-dataobjects</artifactId>
<name>helper-automation-tool-dataobjects</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
</project>
```

helper-automation-tool-core

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>helper-automation-tool</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.proofofconcept.hat</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>helper-automation-tool-core</artifactId>
<name>helper-automation-tool-core</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.proofofconcept.hat</groupId>
        <artifactId>helper-automation-tool-dataobjects</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

I have other dependencies in the core such spring framework or jackson mapper but I excluded them in order to not make the post larger.

When I execute `mvn clean install` on the dataobjects project I get a successful build.

But when it comes to execute the same command on the core I am getting the following:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project helper-automation-tool-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.proofofconcept.hat:helper-automation-tool-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.proofofconcept.hat:helper-automation-tool-dataobjects:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.proofofconcept.hat:helper-automation-tool-dataobjects:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact com.proofofconcept.hat:helper-automation-tool:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT from/to platformServerGADeployement (https://repository.mycompany.com/artifactory/platformserver-ga/): Failed to transfer file: https://repository.mycompany.com/artifactory/platformserver-ga/com/proofofconcept/hat/helper-automation-tool/1.0-SNAPSHOT/helper-automation-tool-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom. Return code is: 409 , ReasonPhrase:Conflict.
```

It seems to be a problem because the core is trying to get the dataobjects project from artifactory because I am using a settings.xml file that has configured some repos on artifactory that are required for this project because we need to download spring and jackson dependencies from there.

Also when I compile the whole thing from the parent project directory I get messages that the dataobjects components does not exist (I am already referencing some classes and interfaces from there).

I wonder to know if there's any way or workaround to solve this issue, maybe I need some additional configuration on the settings.xml or in the pom.xml of the core to consider my local repo.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve this?